# How do I clear the the array of a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging

So this is my code :

```
import React from "react";
import Navigation from './Navigation';
import Foot from './Foot';
import MovieCard from './MovieCard';

class Favorites extends React.Component {

render() {
    const { onSearch, favorites, favoriteCallback, totalFavorites, searchKeyUpdate } = this.props;

    return (
        <div>
            <Navigation
                onSearch={onSearch}
                totalFavorites={totalFavorites}
                searchKeyUpdate={searchKeyUpdate} />


            <div className="container">
            <button onClick={()=> this.clearFavorites(favorites)}> Clear all movies </button>
                {(favorites.length < 1) ?
                    <h1 style={{ fontSize: '13px', textAlign: 'center' }}>Please mark some of the movies as favorites!</h1>
                    :
                    <ul
                        className="movies">
                        {favorites
                            .map(movie => (
                                <MovieCard
                                    movie={movie}
                                    key={movie.imdbID}
                                    toggleFavorite={favoriteCallback}
                                    favorites={favorites}
                                />
                            ))}
                    </ul>
                }
                <Foot />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}


}


const clearFavorites = (favorites) => {
    this.setState({ favorites: [] });

}
```

The thing I need for the button to do is that when i click it that it clears the whole state of favorites. The clearFavorites function is used to clear everything but when I try this I get an error: [image]

Why doesn't this clear the state of favorites?

Comment: `clearFavourites` function isn't part of `class Favourites` - so, that's an issue

Answer (score 2):

As others mentioned, first moving `clearFavorites` function into `Favorites` class.

Second, your `favorites` list is not part of `state` object, but instead you pull it out from `this.props.favorites`, so instead of using `this.setState`, we should just change the props value.

Third, since you're emptying the array, the parameter in your `clearFavorites` probably not needed? Please refer to below:

First we define a constructor to get the value from props and pass it to state in the constructor as below:

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {favorites: this.props.favorites}
}

clearFavorites = () => {
  this.setState({favorites: []});
};
```

Then at last in your `render` method change to following:

```
const { onSearch, favoriteCallback, totalFavorites, searchKeyUpdate } = this.props;
const favorites = this.state.favorites;// Or in your ul tag, instead of using favorites, change it to this.state.favorites
```

Comment: When I do that it gives me this error : https://i.imgur.com/si4osbr.png

Comment: Ok do NOT ever directly mutate a component's props or state like that.

Comment: @Jayce444: You're right, I missed that. Please do have a look at the updated answer. Many thanks for that

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems:

- clearFavorites function is not in your class. So you should put it inside.
- You are trying to clear the data inside the favorites array, which is not part of your state, using the function clearFavorites. So, first of all, you should add favorites array to your state and then you can manipulate the information. I suggest you to use the function getDerivedStateFromProps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to move the clearFavorites into your component

```js
import React from "react";
import Navigation from "./Navigation";
import Foot from "./Foot";
import MovieCard from "./MovieCard";

class Favorites extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const {
      onSearch,
      favorites,
      favoriteCallback,
      totalFavorites,
      searchKeyUpdate
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <div>
        <Navigation
          onSearch={onSearch}
          totalFavorites={totalFavorites}
          searchKeyUpdate={searchKeyUpdate}
        />

        <div className="container">
          <button onClick={() => this.clearFavorites(favorites)}>
            {" "}
            Clear all movies{" "}
          </button>
          {favorites.length < 1 ? (
            <h1 style={{ fontSize: "13px", textAlign: "center" }}>
              Please mark some of the movies as favorites!
            </h1>
          ) : (
            <ul className="movies">
              {favorites.map(movie => (
                <MovieCard
                  movie={movie}
                  key={movie.imdbID}
                  toggleFavorite={favoriteCallback}
                  favorites={favorites}
                />
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
          <Foot />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
  clearFavorites = favorites => {
    this.setState({ favorites: [] });
  };
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It doesn't make any error but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Yes because using `this.setState()` changes that component's own state, whereas you're getting your list of favourites from the parent via `props`. You're conflating `state` and `props`. Either pass down a function from the parent that changes the favourites there (so this component will get a new `favourites` prop), or store the favourites in this component's state and change/render that

Comment: favorites is not a state of Favorites component. You got it from props, so you should clear it where it from.But not in this component.